# pjsip iOS handling ip change during call

Tags: ios, ip-address, pjsip

I want to handle ip change form wifi to 4g and back during an ongoing call using pjsip on ios.
I have followed all the steps form pjsip website: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange and here I have found that the call is disconnected after the `pjsua_acc_set_registration(the_acc_id, PJ_FALSE);` is sent. 
Also I don't figure it out how to send the re registration at point 4.

> "And finally, once unregistration in 2b) above is complete,
>   re-register (with TCP)."

Any advice, suggestion, link to any resource that will hell me solve the issue is well come.

Comment: How did you able to update the transport after reregistering once IP address change. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The most simple and reliable way is described in your [reference](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange#Approach1:Restarteverything):

> The most straightforward solution is of course to restart everything, which means in pjsua terms to call `pjsua_destroy()` and followed by `pjsua_create()`, `pjsua_init()`, and so on.

To detect 4G/WiFi changes, you should use Apple [`Reachability`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) API, great wrappers are [`AFNetworkReachabilityManager`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h) and [`Reachability`](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) by Tony Million. I used this approach in my own project and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thx Maxim, but if you do this and you have an ongoing call the call will be dropped. I have manage to update the transport on IP change in an ongoing call, I will add here how I have implemented when I will find some more time.

Comment: Call dropping was not a big issue in my case, would be interesting to see your solution to this problem :)

Comment: Hey what was your solution to this in the end? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @MaximPavlov, when you do it the call drops and the client actually dials to the other side once again? It actually rings on the other side? Or does the call connect automatically?

Comment: @MichaelKessler in my case it was simple: there was a conference call on the Freeswitch server and if any participant dropped for some reason, it just needed to call the server once again. I understand that in case of p2p calls things become more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Version 2.7 there is second approach there:

> **Approach 2: Selective update**
>
> Alternatively there may be a way to allow the stack to continue to
>   run, updating the address information when necessary. This approach
>   will require some specific features to be used, as well as some
>   actions by the application when it detects that the IP address has
>   changed.
>
> The specific configuration and tasks will be explained below. Note we
>   assume that the SIP and media sockets are bound to INADDR_ANY
>   (0.0.0.0) and not to a specific interface IP address (this is the
>   default behavior).
>
> **Update for 2.7** or above: application can apply this selective update
>   approach with much simpler way, please check ticket [#2041](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/2041).

Comment: have you tried this functionality? I try to use "handleIpChange" function and face problems. It doesn't work all the time.

Comment: Michael Kessler same problem.  It doesn't work all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In Order to get Internet/IP changes, You can use Apple Reachability API or you can use Reachability by Tony. In Reachability change observer you can compare previous IP address family and current IP address family.

If both are from same family e.g last and new belongs to same ip family IPV4 or IPV6 than

1. Get the current call info.
2. Use pjsip method **pjsua_call_reinvite()** and use the flag **PJSUA_CALL_UPDATE_CONTACT**.

If both are from different family e.g last belongs to IPV4 and new belongs to IPV6 or vice versa than use below steps.

1. Send Registration request
2. Get the current call info.
3. Use pjsip method **pjsua_call_reinvite()** and use the flag **PJSUA_CALL_UPDATE_CONTACT**.